# Unable to append div inside div using jquery append

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to a append a div object inside another hardcoded div tag - and then another one inside that. The first append happens fine, but the second append does not happen at all. Not sure why.

Here's the hardcoded html:

```
<body style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Here's the jQuery code:

```
var lastID = 0;
var rootID = "root";
function getNewID() {
    lastID++;
    return (rootID+lastID).trim();
}

$(document).ready(function create() {
        var id1 = loadNewDiv(rootID);
        var id2 = loadNewDiv(id1);
        loadText(id1, "Hello");
    });

function loadNewDiv(parentDiv) {
    var id = getNewID();
    var idTag = "#" + id;
    append(parentDiv, "<div id = \"" + id + "\"></div>");
    return id;
}

function append(id, html) {
    $("#" + id).append(html);
}

function loadText(id, text){
    $("#" + id).text(text);
}
```

Here's the output html, with only one div!

```
<body style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
<div id="root">
<div id="root1"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

The id generator works perfectly fine.

Comment: without the code for loadNewDiv it is impossible to know what id1 is and this may not be what you expect.

Comment: your parentDiv that you are passing to append is a div element, not an id. Thats why your append method isnt working!

Comment: I'm returning the id, not the element.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the $().text function does not append, it overwrites all contents of the element. That removed the div element.